# SQL to group by Group while counting a related column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble grouping the following query together:

```
SELECT id
     , decile_clean
     , COUNT(DISTINCT source) AS unique_sources
  FROM uld_data_combined_rasterized
 GROUP 
    BY id
     , decile_clean
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT source) = 3
```

```
+------------+--------------+----------------+
| id         | decile_clean | unique_sources |
+------------+--------------+----------------+
| a003123084 | Decile4to8   |              3 |
| a003801358 | Decile4to8   |              3 |
| a003867284 | Decile4to8   |              3 |
| a003906322 | Decile4to8   |              3 |
| a013137918 | Decile4to8   |              3 |
| a023038908 | Decile4to8   |              3 |
| a023038981 | Decile4to8   |              3 |
| a023051265 | Decile4to8   |              3 |
| a023061728 | Decile4to8   |              3 |
| a023123080 | Decile9to10  |              3 |
| a023216405 | Decile1to3   |              3 |
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
+------------+--------------+
| decile_clean | count |
+------------+--------------+
| Decile4to8   |          9 |
| Decile9to10  |          1 |
| Decile1to3   |          1 |
```

I have tried to mix a bunch of different queries together for the last 2 hours but cannot seem to get it.

My original table is like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date         | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| source       | varchar(11)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| decile_clean | varchar(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT decile_clean, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT id, decile_clean, COUNT(DISTINCT source) AS unique_sources
      FROM uld_data_combined_rasterized
      GROUP BY id,decile_clean
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT source) = 3
     ) d
GROUP BY decile_clean
```

Comment: You are the  man!  I was kind of close thinking I had to do a from query...but couldn't piece it together.  Thank you so much.  I will accept answer in 9 minutes when it lets me!

Comment: There's no need to have COUNT in the select list, it's only needed in `HAVING`. Or change to `HAVING unique_sources = 3` to avoid redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

For MySql 8.0+ you can use `COUNT()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       decile_clean, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY decile_clean) AS count
FROM uld_data_combined_rasterized
GROUP BY id, decile_clean
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT source) = 3
```

Comment: Awesome to know, unfortunately, I forgot to mention I am running this on 5.6 due to some compatibility issues (GCP does not support 8 yet).